Does rpm -e remove %config files?
If my spec file has Config entries, does rpm -e remove those config files? And, if not, is there a method to uninstall an rpm and remove all config files?

"It depends".
If the config file is unchanged then it will be removed.
If the config file has changed then it will be saved as a .rpmsave file.
For example, here's a very simple package:
Summary: foo
Name: foo
Version: 1
Release: 1
Source0: foo
License: foo

%Description
foo

%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc
install -m 0644 %{SOURCE0} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%config /etc/foo

If I install it with rpm -i ... (or yum or dnf) then I have my config file:
# rpm -i ../RPMS/x86_64/foo-1-1.x86_64.rpm     
# cat /etc/foo
# This is a comment to make a larger file
foo=1

If I now delete the package, it's gone.
# rpm -e foo
# cat /etc/foo
cat: /etc/foo: No such file or directory

However, if I modify the file...
# rpm -i ../RPMS/x86_64/foo-1-1.x86_64.rpm
# echo changed >> /etc/foo
# rpm -e foo
warning: /etc/foo saved as /etc/foo.rpmsave
# cat /etc/foo
cat: /etc/foo: No such file or directory
# cat /etc/foo.rpmsave 
# This is a comment to make a larger file
foo=1
changed

If you wish to ensure the config files are removed, even if changed, then you could look at writing a %preun or %postun section that has a script to remove them.
eg
%postun
echo Cleaning up possible rpmsave savefiles
/bin/rm -f /etc/foo.rpmsave

And now we get the warning and the cleanup
                         
# rpm -i ../RPMS/x86_64/foo-1-1.x86_64.rpm     
# echo changed >> /etc/foo
# rpm -e foo
warning: /etc/foo saved as /etc/foo.rpmsave
Cleaning up possible rpmsave savefiles
# cat /etc/foo /etc/foo.rpmsave
cat: /etc/foo: No such file or directory
cat: /etc/foo.rpmsave: No such file or directory


I will add that as a user, you can remove the files with rpmconf --owner=PACKAGE --clean
